# Error while trying to follow the users in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have error while I trying to follow users, when I click the follow button in some user else profile it's should be I follow him, but the opposite happen he follow me but I'm not follow him

My model

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)

following = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True ,related_name="follow")
```

The view

```
    class AddFollwers(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def post(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        account = Account.objects.get(pk=pk)
        account.following.add(request.user)
        return redirect('account:view', account.pk)

class RemoveFollowers(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def post(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        account = Account.objects.get(pk=pk)
        account.following.remove(request.user)
        return redirect('account:view', account.pk)
```

The urls

```
    path('follower/<int:pk>/add', AddFollwers.as_view(), name='add-follower'),
path('follower/<int:pk>/remove', RemoveFollowers.as_view(), name='remove-follower'),
```

The html template

```
{% if username == request.user.username %}
    
    {% else %}
    
   {% if is_following %}
    <form action="{% url 'account:remove-follower' pk=id%}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Unfollow</button>
        </form>
{% else %}<form action="{% url 'account:add-follower' pk=id%}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Follow</button>
        </form>
    {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: Your view logic `class AddFollwers` is not correct. The `account` should be set to `request.user` and `account.following.add()` to the `user` which matches your `pk` argument.

Comment: Also be sure to mark an answer to your previous questions if they were helpful to your case.

Comment: @Hisham___Pak  can  you clarify the second one `account.following.add()` did you mean this `account.following.add(user=pk)`

Comment: @Hisham___Pak Can you add your answer

Comment: @MohamedSoliman He means you should write `request.user.following.add(account)`.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat this let me when click in follow button redirect me to my own profile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view logic seems incorrect.

```py
class AddFollwers(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def post(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        account = Account.objects.get(pk=pk)
        account.following.add(request.user)
        return redirect('account:view', account.pk)
```

Should be,

```py
class AddFollwers(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def post(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        account = request.user # The currently logged in user.
        follow_account = Account.objects.get(pk=pk) # The account that is to be followed.
        account.following.add(follow_account)
        return redirect('account:view', follow_account.pk) # So it redirects to follow_account user view.
```

Expanded this a lot for you to understand, you can also write it in other ways as AbdulAzizBarkat suggested. Basically you are adding logged in user to the following table of the user that logged in user wants to follow. But expecting the result to be vice-versa.